# cannot find egui dependency when building rust project

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

When I add the egui dependency and try to build the project it cannot resolve the dependency due to the following error:

```
➜  langcard git:(master) ✗ cargo build
    Updating crates.io index
error: failed to select a version for the requirement `egui = "^0.19.0"`
candidate versions found which didn't match: 0.17.0, 0.16.1, 0.16.0, ...
location searched: crates.io index
required by package `langcard v0.1.0 (/Users/admin/Code/rust/langcard)`
```

[image]
Here's the package I am trying to build with:

https://crates.io/crates/egui

Any ideas?

Comment: It can be related with the rustc version, it [requires](https://github.com/emilk/egui/blob/master/crates/egui/Cargo.toml) minimum `1.61`, what's yours ?

Comment: It's version 1.63

Comment: It worked with 1.63 and 2021 edition for me, but I got the same error for 1.53 and 2018 edition, fyi

Comment: What's in your Cargo.toml?

Answer (score 0):

Your **Cargo.toml** file is what contains the dependencies to your project.  It is likely that your referenced version number is not of the proper format, or does not exist.  I would recommend using a static version number, not a "carat requirement", however based on The Book [1] you can use a version such as "0.21" to mean ">= 0.21.0 < 0.22.0".

Based on the current egui crate information, the latest release is: 0.21.0, and on the crate page it shows you what to put into your Cargo.toml:

> egui = "0.21.0"

You can find the link to the crate's page here: https://crates.io/crates/egui

As an example here is a snippet from a Cargo.toml I am currently using:

```ini
[dependencies]
rand = "0.7.0"
structopt = "0.3.21"
# glam = { version = "0.12", features = ["mint"]}
clap = "2.33.3"
gl = "0.14"
egui = "0.16"
egui_sdl2_gl = "0.16.0"
```

As you can see, I am using a bunch of things, some even commented out.

**Try to use the example on the crate's page provided, and see if that helps.**

[1] Link to the Rust Book chapter on dependencies: https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/specifying-dependencies.html